# Which preconditioners make Richardson iteration convergent?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we solve an $m\times n$ full-rank system of equations $Ax=b$ by iterating the following for a small enough $\mu>0$

$$x=x+\mu B(b-Ax)$$

Is there a nice description of kinds of $B$ which make this iteration convergent?
For instance, for $n=1$, $A,B$ can be viewed as vectors, and this iteration converges iff their dot product is positive. What about $n>1$?

1. $B=A^\dagger$ is (trust-region) Newton's method
2. $B=A^T$ is gradient descent on least-squares objective
3. $B=I$ is modified Richardson iteration, only works for positive-definite $A$

Curious if there's a family of methods between 2. and 3. -- converges for any full-rank $A$, but without relying too much on $A^Ty$ (much more expensive than $Ax$ in my application)

**Edit**

- It [seems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PM51R.png) sufficient that $(BA)^T+BA\succ 0$. This means $\mu$ can be made small enough to ensure each step is contractive. However, it is not necessary since for not normal $BA$, convergence may happen after initial transient "hump".
- it is [necessary](https://mathoverflow.net/a/52588/7655) (but [not sufficient](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/52578/eigenvalues-of-sum-of-a-non-symmetric-matrix-and-its-transpose-aat#comment913977_52588)) that all eigenvalues of $BA$ have a positive real part. Negative eigenvalue means you'll be pushed away from solution in those direction.
- which means it is [necessary](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4485727/for-fixed-a-which-matrices-b-make-ba-stable#comment9407939_4485727) that $B=-SA^\dagger$ for some stable matrix $S$ when $n=m$
- It is [sufficient](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4485544/for-which-b-is-ba-positive-definite) that $B=A^T P$ for some positive definite $P$. This ensures update has form to $I-\mu C$ with positive definite $C$
- Last condition seems too restrictive, since we could [use](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.04434) $B=\text{sign}(A^T)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer in Francesca Rapetti course notes [here](https://math.unice.fr/%7Efrapetti/CorsoF/cours3.pdf), preconditioned Richardson can be made convergent iff $BA$ is positive stable, which is true iff $B=SA^\dagger+Z^T$ for some positive stable $S$ and $Z^TA=0$.

[image]

So for instance for the following matrix
$$PA=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 2 & 100 \\
 -300 & 100 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Would set
$$\alpha=\frac{51}{15100}$$

Which gives $\rho(I-\alpha PA)=1$ ([notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/forum-rapetti.nb))

[image]